# ScrollView only on part of the screen in Android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a screen with two parts. I want the top one to be static and the lower one with a TableLayout to be scrollable. I have tried adding a ScrollView to the lower part of the screen, but when making the TableLayout scrollable the top part disappears.

How can I combine the top static part with a scrollable lower part?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="9" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/title_shape">  
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnBack" 
        android:text="@string/titleCreateTest"
        style="@style/Bar_buttonBack">
    </Button>
    <TextView android:layout_weight="6" 
        android:id="@+id/titleFlashcard" 
        android:text="@string/titleStatistic" 
        style="@style/TitleStyle">
    </TextView> 
</LinearLayout>
 <ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    style="@style/TableLayoutStyle">
 <TableRow 
     android:id="@+id/table_row1">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:text="@string/tvRecord" 
            style="@style/TableRowStyle"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1v"
            style="@style/TableRowStyleColumn2"/>
  </TableRow>
  <View
    style="@style/TableRowSeparator"/>
     <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/table_row2">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:text="@string/tvMedium" 
            style="@style/TableRowStyle"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2v"
            style="@style/TableRowStyleColumn2"/>
    </TableRow>
      <View
    style="@style/TableRowSeparator"/>
    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/table_row3">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:text="@string/tvWorst" 
            style="@style/TableRowStyle"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3v"
            style="@style/TableRowStyleColumn2"/>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout> 
   <TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/table_layout2"
    style="@style/TableLayoutStyle">
        <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/table_row4">
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            style="@style/TableRowStyle"/>
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResult"
            style="@style/TableRowStyleColumn2"/>
     </TableRow>
    <View
    android:id="@+id/rowseparator"
    style="@style/TableRowSeparator"/>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It should be easy. Post your layout XML.

Comment: I tried to add my xml layout, but it doesn't show the whole thing. Should I use other that the code brackets {} for xml?

Comment: you need to select together all the lines of xml code and then press the `{}` button, it will add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line (that's what makes lines or blocks code formatted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using both `fill_parent` and `android:weight` can be tricky. There was a discussion about it but I can't find it.

Being your second linear layout (the one with button and textview) set to `fill_parent`, I would expect it to eat up all the space in the root layout, but with a weight set it seems to behave like an "inverse weight" and lets the `ScrollView` take all the space.

It would be better to give the top part a wrap_content in height, and a fill_parent to the `ScrollView`. If you prefer, you could set top part's height=wrap_content and weight=0, and the bottom part's height=0 and weight=1 so that it takes all the space left.

If you set a `ScrollView` to `wrap_content`, it will be wide (or tall) as much as its content. Is it scrolling or just ending up outside the screen?

The `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` is useless, unless you're planning to add something else.

One last note: the `xmlns:android="...."` should stay only in the root element.

Android layout framework is know for being a challenge sometimes, I hope this helped.

Comment: Hi! I found one stackoverflow-q where they were discussing weight and scrollviews, but lost it again. You were right though, it seems the weight in my layout acted as an "inverse weight" and when I removed the weight the layout works as I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: In the [Training for Building your first app on the official developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Weight), there is a brief mention that we should use a `0dp` value for `android:layout_width`/`android:layout_height` if we are also using `android:layout_weight` because `android:layout_weight` already requires a width/height calculation to determine the _remaining space_; and the only reason mentioned is _to improve layout efficiency_.